# Sending mail data from JS to PHP to be mail()'d

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email

I'm having trouble with seemingly simple problem.

Using JQuery i want to POST an array containing 2 items, an email address and email content, to a simple PHP script that mails the customer's concern back to my own server email.

I am receiving the email, but it is blank because either im not encoding or decoding the JSON object correctly or something else.

Javascript:

```
...
var JSONEmailRequest = new Object();
JSONEmailRequest.emailaddress = $("#emailInput").val();
JSONEmailRequest.content = $("#contentInput").val();
$.post("/email.php", JSON.stringify(JSONEmailRequest), function (data) {
    //do stuff
});
...
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $POSTJSONObj = json_decode($POST['JSONEmailRequest']);

    $email_to = "shawnandrews@saportfolio.ca";
    $email_subject = "User enquiry from ".$POSTJSONObj['emailaddress'];
    $email_body = $POSTJSONOb j['content'];

    $result = mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_body,"From: ".$email_to);
    if(!$result) {
        echo false;   
    } else {
        echo true;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't convert the `JSONEmailRequest` to JSON. `$.post` expects the data argument to be either an object or a string in www-form-urlencoded format. So do:

```
$.post("/email.php", JSONEmailRequest, function(data) {
    ...
}, "json");
```

And in the PHP code, use `$_POST` to get the parameters, and `json_encode` to send the result back.

```
<?php

$email_to = "shawnandrews@saportfolio.ca";
$email_subject = "User enquiry from ".$_POST['emailaddress'];
$email_body = $_POST['content'];

$result = mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_body,"From: ".$email_to);

echo json_encode($result);
```